# Type mismatch: cannot convert from MobileElement to List<MobileElement>

Tags: java

I'm getting the following error on the line 31 where it says:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from MobileElement to
> List

I think it was some problem with the import, but after importing "java.util.List;" now I'm getting the error above.

```js
package br.ce.joaobastos.appium;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class FormulárioTeste {
    
    @Test
    public void devePreencherCampoTexto() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("automationName", "uiautomator2");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "C:/Users/prosi/eclipse-workspace/CursoAppium/src/main/resources/CTAppium11-200120-201928.apk");
        
        
        AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), desiredCapabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        
        //Selecionar Formulario
        List<MobileElement> elementosEncontrados = driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.TextView"));
        
        
        
        //Escrever Nome
        
        
        
        //Checar Nome Escrito
        
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

[Print showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEUlk.png)

Comment: It says that you cannot assign it to List<MobileElement>, this method called driver.findElement return only one MobileElement not a List of them.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what I'm going to say is the same thing @MrFisherman said which comes down to interpreting the error you're getting. The error

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from MobileElement to List

Is trying to tell you that the method you are invoking in line 31 which is
`driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.TextView"));`

only returns you one instance of MobileElement so if you change that line to

`MobileElement elementosEncontrados = driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.TextView"));`

The error will dissapear.

Hope it helps. One more thing, I know we in Portuguese put accents in words but I would strongly advise you to refrain from putting accents in code so I would suggest changing the class name to remove the accent.